# Answer Set Programming: How does Graph coloring work? (Explain ASP Code)

Tags: answer-set-programming

My assignment: Graph coloring - Write an answer set program to check if a graph had a 4-coloring and, if it does, the answer set should contain the coloring. If there isn't a coloring, it wont have an answer set. The program should consist of the code to do the 4-coloring and a sample graph representation.

I have this (from ASP Graph Coloring Wikipedia), but I don't understand how exactly it works - could someone please explain this code?

```
c(1..n).                                           
1 {color(X,I) : c(I)} 1 :- v(X).             
:- color(X,I), color(Y,I), e(X,Y), c(I).

v(1..100). % 1,...,100 are vertices
e(1,55). % there is an edge from 1 to 55
```

Answer (score 1):

The code says:

```
c(1..n).
```

You have the facts `c(1)`, `c(2)`, ... `c(n)` which represent the colors. `n` is previously given, in your case `n=4`.

```
1 {color(X,I) : c(I)} 1 :- v(X).
```

*For every vertex `v(X)` exists exactly one assignment `color` from `X` to a possible `c` (color).*
`a {...} b` means that the `...` occurs between `a` and `b` times.
So it means: every vertex has exactly one color. Not more, not less.

```
:- color(X,I), color(Y,I), e(X,Y), c(I).
```

Rules starting with `:-` are constraints: the missing head says the body implies false and therefore the body has to be false as well. It reads:
*It can not be the case that there is an edge `e` from `X` to `Y` where `X` and `Y` have the same color `I`.*
Or in other words: neighboring vertices have different colors.

To get an example graph you add the vertices and egdes you need.